# header is pushed down only in firefox

Tags: css, background, background-image, margins

For some reason my header is being pushed down in firefox. It works fine in safari and chrome. I tried making the header position absolute but it sill is pushed down, when it should float up to the left corner of its parent- it doesn't. So this made me think the body was being pushed down, not the header.

so I started to investigate my background-image position on my body tag, but I have tried all kinds of combinations of positioning the image with no luck, and also

```
.home-body {
    position: relative; 
    top: 0; left: 0; 
}
```

I tried :contain instead of :cover- didn't work.

Then I though it had to do with height: auto, but no.

I have been experimenting with the homepage, although it is happening on all the pages.

here is the site:

http://lindseypod.com/v10/

my body tag:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I have a body.home-page with a background-image with a css cover property:

```
.home-page {
   background: url(images/home_2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover; 

}
```

thenI have a header tag with elements inside of it:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);    
}
```

.header-content is within header:

```
.header-content, 
.footer-content, 
.content, 
.bars-content  {
    width: 96%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    max-width: 960px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this style:

```
#home-mobile{
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The large `margin-top` on `.home-content > h2` is the source of the problem.

One sensible way to fix it is to add `overflow: hidden` to `.home-content`.

This is probably happening in Firefox due to a bug (?) with the handling of [collapsing margins](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins).